# Как научится писать ботов на Python

Tags: python, бот

хочу научится писать ботов на Python, там... для telegram, vk, возможно еще каких-то платформ (я не разбираюсь в этой сфере, поэтому, возможно, вопрос звучит очень неграмотно). Не могли бы подсказать какие-либо источники для изучения?
Думал найти какую-нибудь книгу по описанию всего процесса, но не получилось. Попадались статьи на эти темы и ютуб выдавал несколько видеорликов, но, там как-то все поверхностно, хотелось бы не так.
Просьба не шутить, а то я не пойму)
За ранее, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Не поверхностно чтобы - это читать официальные API надо соответствующих сервисов.

Comment: Какие книги. Книг таких наверное нету) Ищи видео на ютубе, на эту тему их достаточно. Смотришь, запоминаешь, делаешь, если не получается, то приходи сюда(на стэйковерфлов) и описывай свою проблему, от А до Я. Читай про API тех сервисов для которых будешь писать бота. Со временем научишься

Answer (score 1):

Ну давайте попорядку.

1. Книги - не думаю, что такие книги существуют, а если и существуют, то скорее всего плохие.
2. Насчет интернет статей.
   Тут лучше всего читать официальные документации типа для библиотеки telebot - https://core.telegram.org/bots/api
   Так же советую поискать такие статьи на Хабре типа  такого https://habr.com/ru/post/448310/.
3. Видеоуроки на youtube. Тут сложно найти что-то прям хорошее. Но пожалуй можно выделить такие каналы как "Гоша Дударь", "Изучаем мир IT/Олег Шпагин" и "Хауди Хо Просто о мире IT"

P.S. Для неповерхностного изучения Вы не найдете ничего, кроме официальных документаций.